# How could I wait without freezing main thread

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to make a form rolling out from side, but it just teleports

```
class SubWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = loadUi("SubWindow.ui", self)
        butt = QPushButton()
        self.UploadButton.clicked.connect(self.UploadButtonClicked)

    def UploadButtonClicked(self):
        #self.ui.hide()

        for x in range(25):
            self.LoginText.move(self.LoginText.x(), self.LoginText.y()-10)
            self.UploadButton.move(self.UploadButton.x(), self.UploadButton.y()-10)
            self.PassText.move(self.PassText.x(), self.PassText.y()-10)
        #window.Show()

    def Show(self):
        self.ui.show()
    def Hide(self):
        self.ui.hide()
```

I launch this and my program just freeze for few seconds and then everything teleports up, but I want it to be smoother

Comment: Your code isn't valid - you need to indent something into the `for .. in` loop

Comment: Please indent the code in the question like you have it on your computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you want the widget to move smoothly, in that case the solution is to use QPropertyAnimation:

```
def UploadButtonClicked(self):
    animation_group = QParallelAnimationGroup(self)
    for w in (self.LoginText, self.UploadButton, self.PassText):
        start_pos = w.pos()
        end_pos = w.pos() + QPoint(0, -10)
        animation = QPropertyAnimation(
            self,
            propertyName=b"pos",
            targetObject=w,
            startValue=start_pos,
            endValue=end_pos,
            duration=1000,
        )
        animation_group.addAnimation(animation)
    animation_group.start(QParallelAnimationGroup.DeleteWhenStopped)
```